# Blazor with SignalR not render update UI component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

My task is to update the list on demand from hub signalr. I get message from hub and view how call method BroadcastData and call func StateHasChanged, but on page dont updated this list.

```
@page "/Devices"
@using ServerWebB.Repository
@using ServerWebB.Hub
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Cache



<h3>Device</h3>


@foreach (DTO.Device dev in devices)
{
    <p>@dev.Id | @dev.Name | @dev.Online | @dev.LastDateTime</p>
}

@inject IDeviceRepository deviceRepository
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
   
    List<DTO.Device> devices = new List<DTO.Device>();

    private HubConnection? hubConnection;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        devices = await deviceRepository.GetDeviceList();

      
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/info")).Build();

        hubConnection.On<List < DTO.Device >> ("RefreshDevice", devices =>
        {
            BroadcastData(devices);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private async void BroadcastData(List<DTO.Device> payload)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            devices = payload;
           this.StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

I use await InvokeAsync, but it doesn't work again

Comment: I don't think you should use `async void` ever in Blazor, especially if the method only assigns a reference... plus it's not even awaited

Comment: you could try `devices.Clear(); devices.AddRange(payload); `

Comment: Is this server-side Blazor? If so, SignalR is already built in, and you don't need to implement it yourself. See [this blog post](https://www.pixata.co.uk/2021/12/22/mvvm-style-messaging-in-blazor/) for more details

Comment: Which blazor version you have used? .Net 8 or else? Webassembly or server app?

Comment: @BrandoZhang, я использую .net и выбираю тип none, я не знаю, что такое сервер по умолчанию или веб-сборка

Comment: @jeb not working your guess

Comment: We need know that, since I create a test demo by your codes at my side it works well. Besides, could you please tell me how you trigger the RefreshDevice method at your hub?